Exception is caught with catch(Throwable) but not with catch(Exception)
I forgot to copy a jar dependency to the right place so the application crashed due to a ClassNotFoundException. But the Problem is I needed about an hour to figure that out because the Exception is not printed to stderr as expected. So I did following:;
try{
    Vector3D vec = new Vector3D(x, y, z);
}catch(Exception ex){
    logger.catching(ex)
}

nothing!
At this time I already found out that ther was a lib missing but it was weird for me that no exception was printed, neither in the log nor in stderr.
So I tried
try{
    Vector3D vec = new Vector3D(x, y, z);
}catch(Throwable ex){
    logger.catching(ex)
}

And voilla - the Exception is logged propperly.
Any explaination for that? ClassNotFoundException is a subclass of Exception and Exception is a subclass of Throwable - so in my understanding both try-catch-blocks should catch this exception.

Are you sure it wasn't NoClassDefFoundError ?  That's the exception I'd expect to be thrown by your code if the JAR containing Vector3D was missing at runtime. ClassNotFoundException is more likely if you were using Class.forName or similar to load the class explicitly.

Do you still have the logfile that eventually contained the message? Could you provide the previse message and perhaps the stacktrace?

Are you using JDK22? That does not report these type of exceptions correctly due to recently code changes for new main() launchers

@DuncG that's alarming ;)

@g00se Yes very troubling JDK-8329581 and JDK-8330864 and only P3. Its not clear if these bugs apply to this question though.

@DuncG I am using JDK17

That's not the full stack trace. That class could be being loaded elsewhere before your explicit ctor

I missed a part: I got an NoClassDefFoundError caused by ClassNotFoundException - so this explains why I can only catch it with throwable. But why is it not printed to stderr as expected?

@BF_PI because you are getting an error caused by an exception, not an exception directly. There is no introspection of the error's causes when determining whether it is matched by a catch statement.

yeah but If i get rid of the try-catch-block the expected behaviour would be that the Error or Exception stacktrace is printed to stderr which is not!

Why do you expect anything to happen if you remove the catch block? What would do that?

So it seems the only thing missing now, Why doesn't the error show up in stderr. Sometimes logging frameworks or Libraries will change stderr. Does anything show up in stderr in your env?

As @matt wrote in his comment, stderr may be redirected. I suggest you run your code without the logging framework. If you get something written to stderr then your logging framework is redirecting stderr, otherwise you would need to search for something else that is redirecting stderr.

My bad! I was missing that the whole code was in an Thread executed with an ExecutorService. So basically my problem is: link

Does this answer your question? Handling exceptions from Java ExecutorService tasks
